# How to pass the value of the button in the radiobutton on the second page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, radio-button

On first page i have 3 links: basic, standard and premium.
On second page i have radio buttons with 3 options (basic, standard, premium).

I want to achieve that when someone clicks the standard link on the first page, to open a new page with the standard radio option selected.

Buttons on the first page:

```
<a href="/register">basic</a>
<a href="/register">standard</a>
<a href="/register">premium</a>
```

Radiobuttons on the second page:

```
@Html.RadioButton("Package", "basic") basic
@Html.RadioButton("Package", "standard") standard
@Html.RadioButton("Package", "premium") premium
```

Comment: `<a href="/register" id="basic">basic</a>

<script>
    let basic_value = document.getElementById('basic')
    console.log(basic_value.href)
</script>` Here is an example to get a value with Javascript, only since you put a Javascript tag. You then could just simply post the next page, and get the query parameter.

Comment: Hi Raymond, i have tried this but its not working, do I need make some changes on second page to get it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add query to href properties like this:

```
href="register?id=basic"
href="register?id=standard
href="register?id=premium
```

Then in target page check query:

```
@Html.RadioButton("Package", "basic", new { @checked = (Request.QueryString["id"] == "basic"})) basic
@Html.RadioButton("Package", "standard", new { @checked = (Request.QueryString["id"] == "standard"})) standard
@Html.RadioButton("Package", "premium", new { @checked = (Request.QueryString["id"] == "premium"})) premium
```

Note that you may need to change some part of the code

Comment: Thank you, its working, just change brackets like this @Html.RadioButton("Package", "basic", new { @checked = (Request.QueryString["id"] == "basic")})

Comment: Yes. It was because of typying in cellphone :)